Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in a Stored Procedure while using cursor
I have made a SP.
USE [MYDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkUpsertClientMatterInfo]
@ClientMatterInfo dbo.ClientMatterInfoType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @RejectedRows TABLE (
    Client_Number NVARCHAR(50),
    Matter_Number NVARCHAR(50),
    ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
);

DECLARE @Client_ID INT;
DECLARE @Client_Number NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Client_Name NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @Matter_ID INT;
DECLARE @Matter_Number NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @Matter_Name NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @AttyID INT;
DECLARE @PrimaryTpkr NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @OrigTpkr NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @SecondaryTpkr NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @MatterStatus NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @AreaOfLaw NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Date_Created DATETIME;
DECLARE @Closed_Date DATETIME;
DECLARE @LastBilledDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @LastBilledBy NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @EthicalWall NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @LegalHold NVARCHAR(10);

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        Client_ID, Client_Number, Client_Name, Matter_ID, Matter_Number, Matter_Name, 
        AttyID, PrimaryTpkr, OrigTpkr, SecondaryTpkr, MatterStatus, AreaOfLaw, 
        Date_Created, Closed_Date, LastBilledDate, LastBilledBy, EthicalWall, LegalHold
    FROM @ClientMatterInfo;

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
    @Client_ID, @Client_Number, @Client_Name, @Matter_ID, @Matter_Number, @Matter_Name, 
    @AttyID, @PrimaryTpkr, @OrigTpkr, @SecondaryTpkr, @MatterStatus, @AreaOfLaw, 
    @Date_Created, @Closed_Date, @LastBilledDate, @LastBilledBy, @EthicalWall, @LegalHold;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        MERGE INTO dbo.ClientMatterInfo_New AS target
        USING (SELECT @Client_ID AS Client_ID, @Client_Number AS Client_Number, @Client_Name AS Client_Name,
                      @Matter_ID AS Matter_ID, @Matter_Number AS Matter_Number, @Matter_Name AS Matter_Name,
                      @AttyID AS AttyID, @PrimaryTpkr AS PrimaryTpkr, @OrigTpkr AS OrigTpkr,
                      @SecondaryTpkr AS SecondaryTpkr, @MatterStatus AS MatterStatus,
                      @AreaOfLaw AS AreaOfLaw, @Date_Created AS Date_Created,
                      @Closed_Date AS Closed_Date, @LastBilledDate AS LastBilledDate,
                      @LastBilledBy AS LastBilledBy, @EthicalWall AS EthicalWall, 
                      @LegalHold AS LegalHold) AS source
        ON target.Client_Number = source.Client_Number AND target.Matter_Number = source.Matter_Number
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET
                target.Client_ID = COALESCE(source.Client_ID, target.Client_ID),
                target.Client_Name = COALESCE(source.Client_Name, target.Client_Name),
                target.Matter_ID = COALESCE(source.Matter_ID, target.Matter_ID),
                target.Matter_Name = COALESCE(source.Matter_Name, target.Matter_Name),
                target.AttyID = COALESCE(source.AttyID, target.AttyID),
                target.Primary_tpkr = COALESCE(source.PrimaryTpkr, target.Primary_tpkr),
                target.Orig_tpkr = COALESCE(source.OrigTpkr, target.Orig_tpkr),
                target.Secondary_tpkr = COALESCE(source.SecondaryTpkr, target.Secondary_tpkr),
                target.MatterStatus = COALESCE(source.MatterStatus, target.MatterStatus),
                target.AreaOfLaw = COALESCE(source.AreaOfLaw, target.AreaOfLaw),
                target.Date_created = COALESCE(source.Date_Created, target.Date_created),
                target.Closed_date = COALESCE(source.Closed_Date, target.Closed_date),
                target.LastBilledDate = COALESCE(source.LastBilledDate, target.LastBilledDate),
                target.LastBilledBy = COALESCE(source.LastBilledBy, target.LastBilledBy),
                target.EthicalWall = COALESCE(source.EthicalWall, target.EthicalWall),
                target.LegalHold = COALESCE(source.LegalHold, target.LegalHold),
                target.LastActivityDate = GETDATE()
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (Client_ID, Client_Number, Client_Name, Matter_ID, Matter_Number, Matter_Name, AttyID,
                    Primary_tpkr, Orig_tpkr, Secondary_tpkr, MatterStatus, AreaOfLaw, Date_created,
                    Closed_date, LastBilledDate, LastBilledBy, EthicalWall, LegalHold, LastActivityDate)
            VALUES (source.Client_ID, source.Client_Number, source.Client_Name, source.Matter_ID,
                    source.Matter_Number, source.Matter_Name, source.AttyID, source.PrimaryTpkr,
                    source.OrigTpkr, source.SecondaryTpkr, source.MatterStatus, source.AreaOfLaw,
                    source.Date_Created, source.Closed_Date, source.LastBilledDate,
                    source.LastBilledBy, source.EthicalWall, source.LegalHold, GETDATE());
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO @RejectedRows (Client_Number, Matter_Number, ErrorMessage)
        VALUES (@Client_Number, @Matter_Number, ERROR_MESSAGE());
    END CATCH;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO 
        @Client_ID, @Client_Number, @Client_Name, @Matter_ID, @Matter_Number, @Matter_Name, 
        @AttyID, @PrimaryTpkr, @OrigTpkr, @SecondaryTpkr, @MatterStatus, @AreaOfLaw, 
        @Date_Created, @Closed_Date, @LastBilledDate, @LastBilledBy, @EthicalWall, @LegalHold;
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

-- Return rejected rows with error messages
SELECT * FROM @RejectedRows;
END;

I have created this SQL that takes in TVP and I intend to send multiple rows at once. So I use cursor for this case. However in any of the row has error you can see that I am returning a RejectedUsers table.
But in case of wrong datetime data When my cursor maps data from TVP it throws error right there. The ideal case I want is that my all errors should be shown to me via that RejectedUsers table.
See I am trying to run this SP with a wrong date to get an error:
-- Declare a variable of the table type
   DECLARE @TestClientMatterInfo dbo.ClientMatterInfoType;

-- Insert sample rows with valid data only
   INSERT INTO @TestClientMatterInfo (Client_ID, Client_Number, Client_Name, Matter_ID, 
   Matter_Number, Matter_Name, 
                               AttyID, PrimaryTpkr, OrigTpkr, SecondaryTpkr, 
   MatterStatus, AreaOfLaw, 
                               Date_Created, Closed_Date, LastBilledDate, LastBilledBy, 
   EthicalWall, LegalHold)
   VALUES
   (1, 'C1056', 'Client sixty', 101, 'M1051', 'Matter sixty', 1, 'Primary1updated', 
   'Orig1', 'Secondary1','Open', 'Litigation', '2024-01-01G!', '2024-12-01', '2024-01- 
   01', 'User1', 'Yes', 'No'); -- Valid row


   -- Execute the stored procedure with only valid test data
   EXEC BulkUpsertClientMatterInfo @TestClientMatterInfo

But I get error from the SP itself instead of RejectedUsers table.

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 82 Conversion failed when converting
date and/or time from character string.
Completion time: 2024-11-13T13:12:23.4853946+05:00


Why on earth are you using a cursor to perform a merge one row at a time? Why not merge all the rows in one go?

And why do you pass dates as strings which can cause this error? Pass dates as dates and you'll never get this error.

If you are referring that Why would I pass date as string from the backend then its because the data comes from Json Arrayof objects. Since my Json Object quite big I am not adding any validation in my backend rather using a TVP to send my data to Stored Procedure. @DaleK

FYI the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

Also, SQL Server 2008 reached end of life well over 5 years ago. Are you really using such an outdated of date and insecure version? You urgently need to upgrade; the environment is a significant security concern for you, your employers and uour clients.

That's the worst place and way to do it. You should validate as close to the data source as possible. And you should not use try/catch to find validation errors - there is a lot of performance overhead using try/catch. And you should not use a cursor to merge data.

Honestly, this all looks like a massive XY Problem. If you are using a TVP why use a CURSOR? Why not handle your data as what it is, and the thing that SQL Server is best at dealing with: a set. Honestly, my best advice here is bin this attempt and start again, with a set-based solution, and with appropriately data typed columns/parameters.

will do! Thanks @ThomA

@ShahoodAmir this code is unfixable and shows an attempt to hack a complex scenario without understanding it. What is the actual business problem behind this attempt? It's almost certainly solved and answered a dozen times already. Are you trying to UPSERT lots of rows perhaps? There are over a dozen answers. The scalable solution is to insert everything into a staging table and update the target with UPDATE FROM x INNER JOIN x_staging on x.ID=x_staging.ID followed by INSERT ... with a left JOIN.  For a limited number of rows (<50K), a table-vallued parameter can be used instead

DO NOT USE MERGE in any case, it's full of bugs.

the data comes from Json Arrayof object that's no reason to send the strings without parsing.

sorry is your question about why u have an error from variable expecting a Datetime but getting a invalid date value?
regrding cursor, you can use temp table to stage rows, and control amount of rows  to merge into target table.

In any case, to show how unnecessary the cursor is, you can just replace the entire USING clause with USING @ClientMatterInfo  as source to get a MERGE that directly updates the target. You don't even need the table variable, you can add an OUTPUT inserted.* clause to MERGE to get the new data back, or even insert it into eg an audit table or batch table. OUTPUT can be used in any modification query. I use OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO ... to get the IDs of modified rows so I don't have to JOINS million-row tables together
